# Error: Value Cannot be null. Parameter Name: Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a search page. There is a specialization field in which data is coming through EF.

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)
{
    DataTable dt;
    dt = this.GetSPDataTable("getAssociateData");

    List<Associate> list = new List<Associate>();
    list = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
            select new Associate
            {
                AssociateId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AssociateId"]),
                Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                Phone = Convert.ToInt64(dr["Phone"]),
                Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),
                SpecializationId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SpecializationId"]),
                SpcName = dr["SpcName"].ToString()
            }).ToList();
    return View(list.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || search == null).ToList());
    //return View(db.Associates.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || search == null).ToList());
```

here is the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Phone
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Address
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.SpcName
        </td>
```

and at last Model:

```
[Key]
public int AssociateId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a name")]
[MaxLength(10)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Write Your Number ")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Mobile Number.")]
public Nullable<long> Phone { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Where do you dwell")]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Address { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Specialization")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select any of them")]
public Nullable<int> SpecializationId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Specialization")]
public string SpcName { get; set; }
```

I am getting an error on the null.

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || search == null)` why are you checking for `null` **after** attempting to use the value?

Comment: Also, you tagged this with Entity Framework but you are loading to a DataTable? That makes no sense either.

Comment: Check null before loop

Comment: As Camilo Terevinto suggested, try with `.Where(x => search == null || x.Name.Contains(search))` instead. This way, if `search` is `null`, it will not attempt to call `.Contains(null)`

Comment: @ Rafalon Thank you so much, It worked.

Comment: @ Camilo Terevinto  and i only asked for some suggestion. If i knew my mistake i would have never asked this question mr.

Comment: @Rafalon Instead of iterating through the entire collection just to check if `search == null`, a much better approach would be to check if `search != null` and perform the `Where` then

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that's right too, I just suggested the minimum code change to make so it does not break anymore. I'd suggest you post an answer as it would make more sense

Comment: @ Rafalon and if I wanna pass this specialization value in a detail view, How should I do this

Comment: @VishnuSharma if you want to notify someone, don't put a space between the @ and the nickname. I didn't understand your comment, but it looks like it's another specific question, so it might belong in another post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As @CamiloTerevinto suggested:*

Check if `search` is `null` **before** trying to filter by it.

With ternary operator (`?:`):

```
return View(search == null ? list
                           : list.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).ToList());
```

Or on three lines:

```
if(search == null)
    return View(list);
return View(list.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).ToList();
```

---

*I previously suggested the following, but what's below is less efficient:*

```
.Where(x => search == null || x.Name.Contains(search))
```